# Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BufferSource | undefined'.ts(2345)

Tags: javascript, encoding, hash, character-encoding

I have a function to generate a secret hash when given a password and a salt.

```js
import { Base64 } from 'js-base64'

export const generateSecretString = (
  password: string,
  salt: string
): string => {
  const utf8Encoder = new TextEncoder()
  const utf8Decoder = new TextDecoder()
  const shajs = require('sha.js')

  const decodedSalt = Uint8Array.from(Buffer.from(salt, 'base64'))
  const passwordByteArray = utf8Encoder.encode(password)

  const combinedByteArray = new Uint8Array(
    passwordByteArray.length + decodedSalt.length
  )
  combinedByteArray.set(passwordByteArray)
  combinedByteArray.set(decodedSalt, passwordByteArray.length)

  const secretString = shajs('sha256').update(combinedByteArray).digest()

  return utf8Decoder.decode(Base64.encode(secretString))
}
```

This however gives me the following error on the return statement (`Base64.encode(secretString)`):

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BufferSource | undefined'.ts(2345)

I managed to make this work by updating my function to:

```js
import { Base64 } from 'js-base64'

export const generateSecretString = (
  password: string,
  salt: string
): string => {
  const utf8 = require('utf8')
  const utf8Encoder = new TextEncoder()
  const shajs = require('sha.js')

  const decodedSalt = Uint8Array.from(Buffer.from(salt, 'base64'))
  const passwordByteArray = utf8Encoder.encode(password)

  const combinedByteArray = new Uint8Array(
    passwordByteArray.length + decodedSalt.length
  )
  combinedByteArray.set(passwordByteArray)
  combinedByteArray.set(decodedSalt, passwordByteArray.length)

  const secretString = shajs('sha256').update(combinedByteArray).digest()

  return utf8.decode(Base64.encode(secretString))
}
```

What I don't like about this solution is that I'm doing:

```js
const utf8 = require('utf8')
const utf8Encoder = new TextEncoder()
```

This seems redundant to me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I can simplify this function like so:

```js
export const generateSecretString = (
  password: string,
  salt: string
): string => {
  const utf8Encoder = new TextEncoder()
  const shajs = require('sha.js')

  const decodedSalt = Uint8Array.from(Buffer.from(salt, 'base64'))
  const passwordByteArray = utf8Encoder.encode(password)

  const combinedByteArray = new Uint8Array(
    passwordByteArray.length + decodedSalt.length
  )
  combinedByteArray.set(passwordByteArray)
  combinedByteArray.set(decodedSalt, passwordByteArray.length)

  const secretString = shajs('sha256')
    .update(combinedByteArray)
    .digest('base64')

  return secretString.toString()
}
```